# The or A in a photo caption

Tags: articles

I have a book about plants. In one section I am describing a certain species X. In this section, after general description of the plant, I put a photo showing its flower. Now, in the photo caption, should I say "The flower of species X growing in Florida." or "A flower ..." ? What is a difference in meaning?

Makoto

Comment: The standard wording is *Speciosa specialosa growing in Florida*.  Using 'the' means that your photo shows a distinctive form: "The white form of..." Using 'a' is okay for showing one of many of those flowers, but it does not add anything. You can skip all articles. In special cases, you may want to write "A faded SS used in an arrangement with berries."

Comment: Thank you - now the difference is very clear. Using "the" I am saying the photo shows a very typical, general form of the flower of this species. If a photo shows one form of flower out of several different kinds of flowers this species may produce, I would use 'a'.

Comment: 'The flower ...' here specifies the flower as opposed to the leaves, the stem, the roots. 'The' is the correct choice, implying a standard example rather than a solitary bloom (a flower). 'A flower' is often used loosely and synecdochally for 'a specimen of a flowering plant in flower'.

Comment: I agree with Yosef Baskin that it is better just to give the name of the species. If you feel you must explain that the picture shows a flower (the species has insignificant or strange-looking ones) just say "Flower of X growing in Florida".

Answer (score 1):

Since you are putting caption on a singular photo, the caption should be `A flower of species X growing in Florida.` If you had multiple photos, you would say `Flowers of species X growing in Florida.`

As for the difference in meaning:

`"a" signals that the noun is indefinite (it refers to any member of a group)`

`"the" signals that the noun is definite (it refers to a particular member of a group)`

If you wanted to use `the`, you would say `The flower in this photo is of the species X, which can be seen growing in Florida.`

[EnglishPage: A-An-vs-The](http://www.englishpage.com/articles/a-an-vs-the.htm)